# Problemas con la comunicacion serial ARDUINO

Tags: arduino, serialport

he estado utilizando el puerto serie por mucho tiempo , pero ahora me manda muchos espacios al momento de leer, cosa que no debería pasar, alguien tiene el mismo error? , no se si sea la nueva actualización del IDE de arduino o algun problema con sus librerias, espero me puedan ayudar

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  // send data only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
   char incomingByte = Serial.read();

    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte);

  }
}
```

Esta es la salida que me da:

```
I received: 5
I received: 

I received: 1
I received: 

I received: 2
I received: 

I received: 3
I received: 

I received: 4
I received:
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, no se que este pasando :S

Comment: Puede ser CR o LF que esta recibiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que lo imprimas en formato hexadecimal para verificar que no te este llegando el espacio (0x20), para poder imprimir en serial y comprobarlo utiliza:

```
Serial.println(incomingByte,HEX);
```

En caso de que no este llegando el espacio podras verificar realmente que dato hexadecimal te llega por el puerto serial.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas el Serial Monitor en Arduino IDE, éste siempre envia un "\r" (decimal 13) al presionar `Send`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ejemplo, introduje un "5" y presione Send. Arduino recibe un "5" (53) seguido de un "\r" (13).

Tienes que descartar ese valor final.